# Java Object(Boolean,Integer) when add get NullPointerException

Tags: java, object, nullpointerexception

When I try to reset a list Marked I get a Null Pointer Exception.

The problem must be cause I never said what B and C is. (Boolean B, Integer C) And I don't know how to do this.

Here is a part of my code :

```
Marked[] marked;


//Create list marked!
public class Marked<B,C>{
    public B bool;
    public C comp;
}

public Graph(int N)
{

    //Fill marked with false and 0
    marked = new Marked[N];
    for(int i=0;i<N;i++){

        marked[i].bool = false;
        marked[i].comp=0;
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Creating an array of `Marked` doesn't actually initialize the elements in the array:

```
marked = new Marked[N];
for(int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    marked[i] = new Marked<Boolean, Integer>();
    marked[i].bool = false;
    marked[i].comp = 0;
}
```

Comment: @STUDENT_LIFE Don't forget to accept the answer if it has helped you =)

Answer (score 2):

The statement `marked = new Marked[N];` creates a new array of `Marked` objects with `N` elements, but does not initialize them. Each element in this array would be `null`.
You need to manually initialize them by calling the constructor.

So, your for loop should look like this:

```
for(int i=0;i<N;i++) {
    marked[i] = new Marked();
    marked[i].bool = false;
    marked[i].comp=0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you both for your fast reply! :)